# Upgrading Python from 2.4 to 2.5+ on CentOS

Tags: centos, python, update

I tried

`yum update python`

and

`yum upgrade python`

both came up with results with endline: "No Packages marked for Update"

I currently have

```
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Sep  3 2009, 15:37:37)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)] on linux2
```

Apparently, the latest version of python is 3.x already ... what's the best way to upgrade?

Answer (score 3):

Well, the short of it is that you can't (or at least shouldn't).  A lot of CentOS (And RHEL) internal programs (including `yum`) depend upon 2.4...

However, you can install 2.6 from the [epel repository](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories).  The package is named `python26`, and the command is either `python26` or `python2.6` instead of `python`...  Note, don't change the `python` command to point to `python26` for the above reason...

Answer (score 0):

Yum:

```
* A yum repository is available for your convenience. For Fedora Core 3, create "/etc/yum.repos.d/python25.repo" with the following lines:

  [python25]
  name=Fedora Core $releasever - $basearch - Python 2.5
  baseurl=http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.5/rpms/fedora-$releasever/
  enabled=1
  gpgcheck=1
```

Add the KRUD GPG key by running: "rpm --import http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.5/rpms/KRUD-GPG-KEY"

yum install python

it working for me

Answer (score 0):

Just install python from source to a different directory (e.g. /opt/python2.6).  python2.4 is left intact so RHEL/Centos is happy.  You can then use the command python2.6 (or whatever version) all you want to create virtualenvs, run mod_wsgi, etc, etc.  I have this setup running on a RHEL 5 box and it's running Great!

Answer (score -1):

I wrote it about it once [here](http://blog.milford.io/2010/08/new-method-for-installing-python-2-6-4-with-mysql-python-on-centos-5-5/)

Comment: It would be good practice if you include the relevant parts